# How to write Numbers in the Compact-String Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, currency, number-formatting

The **Compact String Form** for writing numbers is recommended by some Style Guides for writing large numbers so that they are easily read and interpreted. Often used in newspapers and magazines.

##### ⚠️ Note ⚠️: *This must not be confused with writing numbers in their full-textual form which is a different requirement (commonly known as numbers to full words conversion) and had been answered extensively on StackOverflow.*

**Some examples,**

the number **22000000** would be written as **22 million**,

the number **77560000000** would be written as **77 billion 560 million**,

---

However, for numbers below 11 (1 to 10) the word is used, **for example**:

the number **3000000** would be written as **three million**.

---

Numbers below 1000 will remain in their number form.

**Other use examples include:**

```
text    : Production exceeded 257456 units last year
becomes : Production exceeded 257 thousand and 456 units last year

text    : Profits exceeded 25000000 US Dollars last year
becomes : Profits exceeded 25 million US Dollars last year

text    : 2000000 people attended the Olympic games
becomes : Two million people attended the Olympic games
```

Answer (score -2):

The following function `numToCompactWords(number)` converts a number to its Compacted Number-Words equivalent.

An additional function `stringToCompact(string)` takes an input as a string and returns a string with integer numbers converted to compact number-words format using the `numToCompactWords(number)` function. This function can be improved to handle (say) decimal numbers as necessary and skip numbers inside quotes if needed. However, I have added it to give a simple use-example.

Included below are some test cases together with example textual ouputs.

```js
/********************************************************
* @function    : numToCompactWords(number)
* @purpose     : Converts numbers to Compacted Number-Words
* @version     : 1.00
* @author      : Mohsen Alyafei
* @date        : 11 Mar 2022
* @param       : {number} integer numeric or string
* @param       : [smart] flag (default true);
*                false: uses numbers always even for numbers below 10
* @returns     : {string} The Compacted Number-Words string
********************************************************/
function numToCompactWords(num=0,smart=true) {
if (num == 0) return "zero";
num = ("0".repeat(2*(num+="").length%3)+num).match(/.{3}/g);
let out="", scale=["","thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion"];
return num.forEach((n,i) => {
n=+n;
if (n) {
    if (smart && n<11) n=["","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"][n];
    let L=num.length-i-1;
    out+= (L || num<=999 ?"":" and") + (out?" ":"") + n + (scale[L]?" ":"") + scale[L];
    }
}),out;
}
//=========================================
//             Test Code
//=========================================
var r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(0,"zero");
r |= test(5,"five");
r |= test(10,"ten");
r |= test(19,"19");
r |= test(33,"33");
r |= test(100,"100");
r |= test(111,"111");
r |= test(890,"890");
r |= test(1234,"one thousand and 234");
r |= test(12345,"12 thousand and 345");
r |= test(123456,"123 thousand and 456");
r |= test(1234567,"one million 234 thousand and 567");
r |= test(12345678,"12 million 345 thousand and 678");
r |= test(123456789,"123 million 456 thousand and 789");
r |= test(1234567890,"one billion 234 million 567 thousand and 890");
r |= test(12012,"12 thousand and 12");
r |= test(120012,"120 thousand and 12");
r |= test(1200012,"one million 200 thousand and 12");
r |= test(12000012,"12 million and 12");
r |= test(120000012,"120 million and 12");
r |= test(75075,"75 thousand and 75");
r |= test(750075,"750 thousand and 75");
r |= test(7500075,"seven million 500 thousand and 75");
r |= test(75000075,"75 million and 75");
r |= test(750000075,"750 million and 75");
r |= test(1000,"one thousand");
r |= test(2000000,"two million");
r |= test(10000000000,"ten billion");
r |= test(5000000000000,"five trillion");
r |= test("1000000000000000","one quadrillion");

if (r==0) console.log("All Test Units Passed.");
//============================================
function stringToCompact(s){
s =s.trimStart().split(" ");
for (let i in s)
if (Number.isInteger(+s[i])) {
s[i] =numToCompactWords(s[i]);
if (i==0) s[i]=s[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s[i].substring(1);
}
return s.join(" ");
}
//============================================
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("Examples to Convert numbers inside text:")
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log(stringToCompact("Over 120000 attended the exhibition last week"));
console.log(stringToCompact("World population is 7750000000"));
console.log(stringToCompact("Production exceeded 257456 units last year"));
console.log(stringToCompact("Profits exceeded 25000000 US Dollars last year"));
console.log(stringToCompact("There are 20000 books and 25 magazines"));
console.log(stringToCompact("2000000 people attended the Olympic games"));



//============================================
function test(n,should) {
let result = numToCompactWords(n);
if (result !== should) {console.log(`${n} Output   : ${result}\n${n} Should be: ${should}`);return 1;}
}
```

Comment: It is basically for English as a default example. But can be easily changed to other similar languages.